# Making a box with a coloured header in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a box like the following in HTML and CSS:

[image: (insert picture)]

I have the following code:

orders.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Orders Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="orders.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="order-container">
            <div class="order-header">
                <p>ORDER #10980<p>
            </div>
            <div class="order-list">
            </div>
            <div class="order-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

orders.css:

```
.order-container {
    border-style: solid;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

.order-header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #a9dbde;
    height: 60px;
}
```

I want the blue header to align with the top of the box. However, there is a white space between the blue header and the top of my box, as seen in the following image. I am not sure how to make the top of the header align with the top of the box. Any insights are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the default margin from the `<p>` tag. Something like `p{margin:0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has some default value like @khan said. Also you can try flex property in css, it will help u a lot when doing some element align operation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Making a box with a coloured header in HTML and CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .order-container{
            border: 1px solid #999;
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        .order-header{
            text-align: center;
            height: 50px;
            background: #81CCD3;
        }
        .order-header p{
            margin:0 ;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="order-container">
        <div class="order-header">
            <p>ORDER #10980</p>
        </div>
        <div class="order-list">
        </div>
        <div class="order-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers have default styles that you have to override and the browser you are using is adding a margin to `p` element.

I recommend you use one of the header tags for your element (more semantic).

```
<h1 class="order-header">ORDER #10980<h1>
```

And remove margins

```
.order-header {
    margin: 0;
    ...
}
```

You can use `font-size` to adjust text size and `line-height` to center the text vertically (you can remove `height` if you do this).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default margin from the `p` tag. Here's a list of [default values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.order-container {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.order-header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #a9dbde;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-container">
  <div class="order-header">
    <p>ORDER #10980
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="order-list">
  </div>
  <div class="order-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```